# How to Increment Page Numbers by 2 in the A-1, A-2, etc. Format?

Tags: microsoft-word

I have field codes that currently work when an 11x17 page counts as two pages:

- First 11x17 page number: 1/2
- Second 11x17 page number: 3/4

My question is "How do I increase an 11x17 page number by 2 AND also include Section Numbers (1-1/1-2, 1-3/1-4 or preferably first page number A-1/A-2 and 2nd page number A-3/A-4)?

Thank you in advance,
Leeka

Comment: If your current field codes are not simple { PAGE } field codes, can you please tell us what they contain? (maybe there is a calculation in them, for example).

Comment: Tanya, I really appreciated your response to my question months ago. This would have definitely solved my problem with numbering 11x17 pages for appendices, but I was unsuccessful with trying to get the "STYLEREF" to be pulled into the table of contents.

Answer (score 1):

If you have used a style for your Section headings (in this example I've just created a style called SectionA).

You can use a STYLEREF field to insert the "A" number for your section number, and then an = field to work out 2 page numbers (2n-1 for the odd number and 2n for the even number, where n is the current 11x17 page).

[image]

In the above picture, you can see the field codes, and below the results of those field codes.

The \n switch in the STYLEREF field tells Word to insert the number (not the text) of the paragraph formatted with the SectionA style.